# Reset variable on spinner exit by back button press

Tags: android, android-spinner

I would like to update a variable when the user decides to exit my app when a particular spinner was displayed.

I tried doing this by overriding onBackPressed, but it is not called when the user exits the spinner via the back key even though the spinner is killed.

This also does not work:

```
imageShareOpts.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Log.i("test12", "Back key listener in spinner");
            spinnerNotDefault = false;
            imageShareOpts.setSelection(-1);
           }
        return false;
    }                       
});
```

I have also tried to overide onkeyDown() it is also no called:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Here to implements for your code.
        spinnerNotDefault = false;
        Log.i("test12", "onkeyDown spinnerNotDefault:"+spinnerNotDefault);
        Log.d(TAG, "KEYCODE_BACK");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: is that spinner dialog?

Comment: It's an android spinner from:android.widget.Spinner.imageShareOpts is my spinner.